# Animation drawable in ListView row

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview

I encountered following problem. I have a `ListView` where every row looks like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:duplicateParentState="true" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/dashplayer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:tag="1"
    android:src="@android:color/transparent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/name"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Camera name"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So far so good, then I have an adapter with `getView` method like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String name = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.dash_row, parent, false);
    ImageView iv=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dashplayer);

    if(!cameras.get(position).isActive()){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noise);  // HERE COMES THE ANIMATION
    }else{
        iv.setImageBitmap(cameras.get(position).getCurrentFrame()); //static bitmap, works fine
    }
   return convertView;
}
```

First it inflates the xml given above and after that puts into `ImageView` either an animation drawable or static bitmap. Bitmap works well, but the problem is with the animation.
It is defined in xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame0" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame1" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame2" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame3" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame4" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame5" android:duration="80" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame6" android:duration="80" />
</animation-list>
```

What troubles me is that the animation stops after a while (possibly when I call `notifyDatasetChanged`, but I am not sure on this one). After I scroll the list it starts playing again. I can also make it play by calling `listView.scrollListBy(0);`(or something similar in older API), but still the animation is somewhat choppy.

Does anyone have any idea, why the animation stops ?

Answer (score 0):

```
iv.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.noise));
//depending on your android version code, setBackgroundDrawable in older versions
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) iv.getBackground();
```

put `animationDrawable.setVisible(true,true)` instead of `animationDrawable.start()` and it will work just fine

Comment: I never used animationDrawable.start(). It starts automatically.I tried animationDrawable.setVisible(true,true) as you suggested, but it doesnt do anything really. Still the same problem.